# How do I select an element with class A which is under another element with class B?

Tags: html, css

Here is a simplified snippet of my code:

```
<li id="work-5" class="work-5 class-B">
    <div>some other stuff</div>
    <div class="class-A"></div>
</li>
<li id="work-6" class="work-6 class-C">
    <div class="class-A"></div>
</li>
```

I want to apply some CSS styling to the element with class-A which is under the tree of an element with class-B. In other words I want to apply a different style to two elements with the same class (class-A) which are somewhere (not necessarily first child) under the tree of two different elements with distinct classes. Can I use CSS selectors to achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basic CSS:

```
.class-B .class-A {
   ...
}
```

Comment: are you sure that applies to this case? I have tried this but for some reason its not working for me.

Comment: Yes, it applies to this case. The above applies to any `.class-A` which has a `.class-B` as a parent anywhere above it.

Comment: thanks for your response. It is working now. It was a silly mistake on my side.

Answer (score 0):

Two class selectors and a descendant combinator!

```css
.class-B .class-A {
    /* ... */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure can. Just use the parent class to target it.

http://jsfiddle.net/DpddQ/

```
.class-B .class-A { background: blue; color: white; }
.class-C .class-A { background: red; }
​
```

Answer (score 0):

yes, there are a lot of alternatives to this:

```
#work-5 .class-A { }
#work-6 .class-A { }
```

or

```
.work-5 .class-A { }
.work-6 .class-A { }
```

or

```
#work-5.work-5 .class-A { }
#work-6.work-6 .class-A { }
```

or

```
#work-5.work-5.class-B .class-A { }
#work-6.work-6.class-C .class-A { }
```

Depending on your needs, but the more specific your selector is, the more it has precedence.